# Akka Streams buffer on SubFlows based on parent Flow

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http, reactive, alpakka

I am using akka-streams and I hit an exception because of maxing out the Http Pool on akka-http.
There is a Source of list-elements, which get split and thus transformed to SubFlows.
The SubFlows issue http requests. Although I put a buffer on the SubFlow, it seems the buffer takes effect per SubFlow.
Is there a way to have a buffer based on the Source that takes effect on the SubFlows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I was merging the substreams without taking into consideration the parallelism by using

```
def mergeSubstreams(): Flow[In, Out, Mat]
```

From the documentation

> This is identical in effect to `mergeSubstreamsWithParallelism(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`.

Thus my workaround was to use

```
def mergeSubstreamsWithParallelism(parallelism: Int): Flow[In, Out, Mat]
```